# Dynamically assigning the name to text boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am running a loop to generate the text boxes and I want the loop variable to be appended to the name attribute of the text boxes generated. Please find below code for reference :

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" 
    id="row" {{t}} 
    ng-if="true === isShow[emp.indexOf(empId)][t]">

  <td>
    <input type="text" 
            maxlength="20" 
            class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" 
            name="textVal" 
            ng-pattern="regexText" 
            ng-model="empKeys[emp.indexOf(empId)][t]" 
            style=" width: 100%;height:30px;" 
            placeholder="please enter val here......">
    <div ng-messages="employees.textVal.$error">
      <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid Text</div>
    </div>
  </td>
```

and so on...

I want that the loop variable `t` and the value of `emp.indexOf(empId)` should also be appended in the textbox created above so that every textbox has a unique name and I can apply the `ng-messages` uniquely.

Comment: `ng-message` is more angular than jQuery actually, isn't it?

Comment: Yes .... sorry should have tagged angularjs not jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for the string values like `name` and `id` put the `{{t}}` inside the attribute value quotes

```
id="row{{t}}"

name="textVal{{t}}"
// or
name = "{{'textVal' + t}}"
```

You need to use `[]` object notation for the `ng-messages` parent property

```
ng-messages="employees['textVal' + t].$error"
```

Comment: Thanks now I am able to give the id but not able to pass it in the ng-messages. When I try to set the ng-messages like below I am getting an error 
"employees[{{'textVal'+emp.indexOf(empId)+t}}].$error"

The error is Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 18 of the expression

Comment: This worked employees['textVal'+emp.indexOf(empId)+t].$error. Thanks a lot

Comment: Might try using `ng-init` to create child scope variable to do the `indexOf()` part for whole row

Comment: This worked employees['textVal'+emp.indexOf(empId)+t].$error. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ahhh right...not sure what I was thinking putting the `{{}}` in there